# Azure Websites - 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

My web app is running fine on my local machine but when published to a Windows Azure Website, I get the following error on one of the controller action methods:

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

I used Elmah to capture more information and I get:
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2

So it's referencing when I use path.combine(path1, path2) in my method. I can't figure out what is going on, the input file is being read fine and the output files are being generated fine when I check the output directory.

Any other suggestions on what might be going on?

Here is the code for my action method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessProducts(UploadViewModel model)
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime endTime;
            TimeSpan totalTime;            
            PulProcessor prodManager = new PulProcessor();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/files/incoming"), model.ProductsFileName);

            try
            {                
                using (TextReader prodFile = System.IO.File.OpenText(filePath))
                {
                    CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(prodFile);
                    // map is at end of this file
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PulMap>();
                    List<PulProduct> prodList = csv.GetRecords<PulProduct>().ToList();

                    foreach (var product in prodList)
                    {
                        prodManager.ProcessProduct(product);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            }
            string currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            string productFileName = "PUL" + currentDate + ".txt";
            string exceptionsFileName = "PUL" + currentDate + "belowcost.txt";

            WriteFile(prodManager.Products, productFileName);
            WriteFile(prodManager.BelowCost, exceptionsFileName);

            endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            totalTime = endTime - startTime;

            ViewBag.StartTime = startTime.ToString();
            ViewBag.EndTime = endTime.ToString();
            ViewBag.TotalTime = totalTime.ToString();
            ViewBag.TotalOutput = prodManager.Products.Count.ToString();
            ViewBag.ProductCounter = prodManager.RecordsProcessed;
            ViewBag.FileName = productFileName;
            ViewBag.ExFileName = exceptionsFileName;
            ViewBag.Exceptions = prodManager.BelowCost.Count.ToString();

            return View();
        }

    private void WriteFile(List<PulFinalProduct> prodList, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/files/pul"), fileName);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
            StringBuilder fileHeader = new StringBuilder();

            fileHeader.Append("Inventory Number\t");
            fileHeader.Append("MPN\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Retail Price\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Seller Cost\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Buy It Now Price\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Starting Bid\t");
            fileHeader.Append("ChannelAdvisor Store Price\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Quantity\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Quantity Update Type\t");
            fileHeader.Append("UPC\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Weight\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Brand\t");
            fileHeader.Append("Manufacturer\t");

            using (writer)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(fileHeader.ToString());

                foreach (var product in prodList)
                {
                    StringBuilder productLine = new StringBuilder();
                    productLine.Append(product.InventoryNumber + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.MPN + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.RetailPrice.ToString() + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.SellerCost.ToString() + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.BINPrice.ToString() + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.StartingBid.ToString() + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.CAStorePrice + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.Quantity + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.QUType + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.UPC + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.Weight + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.Brand + "\t");
                    productLine.Append(product.Manufacturer + "\t");

                    writer.WriteLine(productLine.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is what the Azure Eventlog gives me:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2 at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) at Jemco.Web.Controllers.PartsUnlimitedController.ProcessProducts(UploadViewModel model) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

OK, I was able to do remote debugging on this azure site. The code inside my controller action is running fine. After I get the original 502 error, the controller continues to process the input data and then write the output files. Everything works fine and the only problem I'm having is getting a 502 page while I am waiting for it to process and load the next view. Does a controller have a certain amount of time to return a view and if it doesn't is this why I'm getting the 502 error?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure what I'm experiencing is a timeout error because my controller method takes too long to run. I probably can't speed up the controller method so I'm not sure what I can do. I don't think I can or should change timeout settings on the server so maybe there something using ajax that can be done like sending a status update to the browser after every so often. I'm totally new to this so I'll have to do some research.

Comment: Do you have [failed request logging](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/) enabled in your site? It might be useful to get some error messages from IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the whole subroutine was taking way too long to function and was timing out hence the 502 error. I solved this by re-writing the class to use SignalR to run the task to create the file and then update the user as to the progress that was being made.